# API keys or Client Credentials flow? Good practice to control application access to a deployed web component

Tags: api, oauth2, token, web

**Company A** developed a **widget** (Web Component) deployed on several clients/partners.

Only clients/partners must be authorized to use the widget.
No need to distinguish between each end users (clients' users), because only the application itself, the widget itself must be authenticated/authorized.

I thought about using a relevant API KEY per client stored on a reverse proxy (mini-backend), the latter stored on the client's infrastructure.
This way, the widget could target the reverse proxy, this one providing the hidden API KEY in order to deal with Company A's backend.

Pros of this solution:
No front developments required on client's infrastructure.
Cons:
If the API is stolen (in extreme cases), as there is no expiration by default, anyone could benefit of its power at any time except if additional check on domain + IP/DNS are carried out.

Other way, what about the Client Credentials flow of OAuth, that would consist in ensuring a communication between Company A's backend AND client's backend to generate a token allowing client/partner to ask for a **business** token that can expire in a short run.
Thus, the widget would be passed the business token in order to deal with Company A's backend features at any time, before expiration.

Pros of this solution:
The token can expire and has therefore less potential of damages than a potential stolen API KEY that does not expire.
Cons:
Backend developments required on clients side in order to deal with the client credentials flow (service to service).
Front developments required on client's infrastructure to provide the business token to the widget.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Please clarify my understanding of your two options:  1) `CLIENT-APP <> CLIENT-PROXY <> WIDGET-MAKER-API`  and option 2)  `WIDGET-MAKER-AUTH <> CLIENT-APP <> WIDGET-MAKER-API` , where `<>` is bi-directional comm's and `CLIENT` is within the client/ partner's org and `WIDGET-MAKER` is within **Company A**

Comment: @brynk 1) Widget in Javascript => Client backend proxy (reverse proxy hidding API_KEY towards Company A's backend
2) Widget in Javascript using Token generated by a communication Client_Backend => Company's A backend, that allows Widget to talk directly with Company's A backend thanks to this business token.